# display a single record which includes like name ,age etc. in java

Tags: java

hi my code is displaying the whole record but i just need to display a single record.

```java
BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("CUSTOMER.txt"));

while ((name = buff.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Comment: so, is there all the name age written in one single line or in multiple line?

Comment: Could you please share a example line ?

Comment: We have no idea what's the meaning of the "record" and what 's the content of your text file. Please add more details and the output of current program.

Answer (score 0):

You are displaying all records with a loop. If you get rid of loop, your code will display single record

```java
while ((name = buff.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

to

```java
if ((name = buff.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(name);
}
```